# Question was closed as duplicate but is a different question

Tags: discussion, question-closure, vote-to-reopen

The question [Why did English take the "mix pronunciations and spellings" route instead of one rule route like French, or separate languages/dialects like Spanish?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/611283/why-did-english-take-the-mix-pronunciations-and-spellings-route-instead-of-one) was closed as a duplicate of [Why English pronunciation differs so much from written language, compared to German?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1071/why-english-pronunciation-differs-so-much-from-written-language-compared-to-ger).

The linked question is about *where differences in English came from.*

I asked why England *then left it like that* and didn't impose one set of rules or keep languages separate. A different, unanswered question.

It seemed like people just thought it was too much for then to answer, but why restrict others from trying?

Update 8/16/23: Once again, the question is closed for not being clear, though people clearly understood it. It's about history, why things ended up the way they are, with mixed pronunciations, rather than one, like French or Spanish.

Comment: "English" didn't take that route. Educators did. Your question isn't really about the language per se but about culture.

Comment: However you wanna describe it, it turned out different than others for reasons, since other countries clearly had multiple influences also

Comment: English was a German dialect later influenced by Scandinavian Germanic dialects later influenced by late medieval French, a Romance dialect. It is a confluence of rivers of different colors.

Comment: I know, that wasn't the question though. I keep repeating myself, but some people get it.

Comment: You can't impose rules on language. You can impose rules on spelling, but you still have the large "installed base" of texts to deal with when you want to change the spelling of a word because the extant spelling no longer reflects its pronunciation. You're putting those older texts out of reach. And language will keep on changing, so there would have to be spelling reform after spelling reform. There have been spelling reforms, so the situation was not simply left "as is".

Comment: However you wanna call it, France imposes rules, and Spain kept other languages separate. You're caught up on semantics, the question is over the actions taken or not. Which left english with different ways for saying 'ough', for example.

Comment: Those are Romance languages rather than a hybrid of German and French, as English is.

Comment: There are other languages in Spain, and to a smaller scale France, and yet they don't have a mix of ways to say how something is written. France has German borrowed words from other languages also fyi, like german. You seem to be totally missing the point of the question. It's really not that complicated. English is not the only language with a mix of word origins, yet it keeps a mix.

Comment: It's not just loan words but an amalgamation at all levels.  You seem to have an axe to grind. What do you want people to say, "England was remiss"?

Comment: Yeah, Spain didn't have an amalgamation, why was the different route taken? Look at Normandy, you know why they call it at? And yet there aren't words from there that are said differently in french. Why was it different than there also?

Comment: It's a question about history. I don't care about axes.

Comment: All languages have multiple origins. If you want to say that the influences were too close to evenly spread out for one to have the sole influence and impose pronunciation rules, that would be an answer.

Comment: In England, the third wave (French) was a language markedly different from the Scandinavian-influenced German that preceded it. It brought not only nouns but verbs with different complement-licensing patterns and morphology. Moreover, speakers of English in the northern parts of the country had a rather different pronunciation from that of those living in the south, and that difference accounts for some of the modern-day spelling artefacts.

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase the question as, 'did people England try to impose one set of rules for the language, or keep languages separate, as has been done elsewhere?'

Comment: When you say "languages" do you mean "dialects"? Not sure I follow.

Comment: I know what those words mean.

Comment: I don't know what you mean then by "keep languages separate".

Comment: Other people understand the question clearly, don't think I can help you anymore.

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by "keep languages separate".  I don't think I need your help, except in explaining what you mean.

Comment: @TimR, you keep engaging the OP's substantive question, while the question **here** is a meta-question about the closing of the substantive question. What you are saying here could be a part of the answer to the substantive question rather than a reason for its closing.

Comment: @jsw29: I didn't even notice what site I was on. I wear bifocals and the address-bar and banner are a blur (since I'm reading through the lower lens and not tilting my head back). I saw the big **English Language and Usage** but not the tiny "meta".

Answer (score 1):

The question has had its three votes to reopen.

Comment: It just got one to reclose. I suspect indefeasable ignorance.

Comment: @JohnLawler, you may have a good reason for closing the question, but it would be helpful to everybody if you stated your reason explicitly, rather than dismissing any possible disagreement with it as a manifestation of 'indefeasible ignorance'. The boilerplate reason that appears in the banner seems out of place; as the OP convincingly points out it is problematic to say that the question is unclear if a competent contributor to this site understood it well enough to answer it.